# Почему не работают комментарии в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Привет всем, делаю кастомную тему Wordpress и возникла проблема с комментариями, при попытке добавления нового комментария открывается файл **wp-comments-post.php**, но ничего не происходит - просто пустой(белый) экран. В файле темы **single.php** подключаю шаблон комментариев так:

```
<div id="comments" class="box comments"><?php comments_template('', true);?></div>
```

Файл **comments.php**, который подключается в файле *single.php*:

```
<?php $args = array(
     'avatar_size'      => 50,
     'reply_text'       => __('Ответить', "devhelper"),
     'callback'         => 'mytheme_comment',
     'reverse_children' => true,
     'per_page'         => 0
    );

?>

<!--<h3>Комментарии к посту «<?php the_title();?>»</h3>-->
<div class="main-list-comments">    
    <ul>
        <?php wp_list_comments($args); ?>
    </ul>
</div>

<?php if (!comments_open()){ // <p class="nocomments">Комментарии запрещены</p> ?>

<?php }else{ ?>
        <?php if (!get_comments_number()) :?>
            <p class="nocomments">Ответов пока нет, будьте первым.</p>
        <?php endif;?>
<?php } ?>

<?php
$fields =  array(
    'author' => '<div id="author-data"><p class="answer-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Имя' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
                '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
    'email'  => '<p class="answer-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
                '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
    'url'    => '<p class="answer-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Сайт' ) . '</label>' .
                '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /></p></div>',
);

$comments_args = array(
        'fields' => $fields
        ,'comment_notes_after' => ''
        ,'comment_field' => '<p class="answer-form-comment"><label for="textarea-answer">' . _x( '', '' ) . '</label><textarea id="textarea-answer" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>'
        ,'label_submit' => __( 'Ответить', 'devhelper' )
        ,'logged_in_as' => ''
        ,'title_reply' => __( '' )
);

comment_form($comments_args);

?>

<script>
var editor = new TINY.editor.edit('editor', {
    id: 'textarea-answer',
    width: "100%",
    height: 175,
    cssclass: 'tinyeditor',
    controlclass: 'tinyeditor-control',
    rowclass: 'tinyeditor-header',
    dividerclass: 'tinyeditor-divider',
    /*controls: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', '|', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|',
        'orderedlist', 'unorderedlist', '|', 'outdent', 'indent', '|', 'leftalign',
        'centeralign', 'rightalign', 'blockjustify', '|', 'unformat', '|', 'undo', 'redo', 'n',
        'font', 'size', 'style', '|', 'image', 'hr', 'link', 'unlink', '|', 'print'],*/
    controls: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', '|', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|',
        'orderedlist', 'unorderedlist', '|', 'outdent', 'indent', '|', 'leftalign',
        'centeralign', 'rightalign', 'blockjustify', '|', 'unformat', '|', 'undo', 'redo',
        '|', 'image','link', 'unlink', '|'],
    footer: true,
    fonts: ['Verdana','Arial','Georgia','Trebuchet MS'],
    xhtml: true,
    cssfile: 'custom.css',
    bodyid: 'editor',
    footerclass: 'tinyeditor-footer',
    toggle: {text: 'source', activetext: 'wysiwyg', cssclass: 'toggle'},
    resize: {cssclass: 'resize'}
});
</script>
```

Вот файл **wp-comments-post.php**, который обрабатывает комментарии:

```
<?php

    /**
     * Handles Comment Post to WordPress and prevents duplicate comment posting.
     *
     * @package WordPress
     */

    if ( 'POST' != $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
        header('Allow: POST');
        header('HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed');
        header('Content-Type: text/plain');
        exit;
    }

    /** Sets up the WordPress Environment. */
    require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

    nocache_headers();

    $comment_post_ID = isset($_POST['comment_post_ID']) ? (int) $_POST['comment_post_ID'] : 0;

    $post = get_post($comment_post_ID);

    if ( empty($post->comment_status) ) {
        do_action('comment_id_not_found', $comment_post_ID);
        exit;
    }

    // get_post_status() will get the parent status for attachments.
    $status = get_post_status($post);

    $status_obj = get_post_status_object($status);

    if ( !comments_open($comment_post_ID) ) {
        do_action('comment_closed', $comment_post_ID);
        wp_die( __('Sorry, comments are closed for this item.') );
    } elseif ( 'trash' == $status ) {
        do_action('comment_on_trash', $comment_post_ID);
        exit;
    } elseif ( !$status_obj->public && !$status_obj->private ) {
        do_action('comment_on_draft', $comment_post_ID);
        exit;
    } elseif ( post_password_required($comment_post_ID) ) {
        do_action('comment_on_password_protected', $comment_post_ID);
        exit;
    } else {
        do_action('pre_comment_on_post', $comment_post_ID);
    }

    $comment_author       = ( isset($_POST['author']) )  ? trim(strip_tags($_POST['author'])) : null;
    $comment_author_email = ( isset($_POST['email']) )   ? trim($_POST['email']) : null;
    $comment_author_url   = ( isset($_POST['url']) )     ? trim($_POST['url']) : null;
    $comment_content      = ( isset($_POST['comment']) ) ? trim($_POST['comment']) : null;

    // If the user is logged in
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( $user->exists() ) {
        if ( empty( $user->display_name ) )
            $user->display_name=$user->user_login;
        $comment_author       = $wpdb->escape($user->display_name);
        $comment_author_email = $wpdb->escape($user->user_email);
        $comment_author_url   = $wpdb->escape($user->user_url);
        if ( current_user_can('unfiltered_html') ) {
            if ( wp_create_nonce('unfiltered-html-comment_' . $comment_post_ID) != $_POST['_wp_unfiltered_html_comment'] ) {
                kses_remove_filters(); // start with a clean slate
                kses_init_filters(); // set up the filters
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ( get_option('comment_registration') || 'private' == $status )
            wp_die( __('Sorry, you must be logged in to post a comment.') );
    }

    $comment_type = '';

    if ( get_option('require_name_email') && !$user->exists() ) {
        if ( 6 > strlen($comment_author_email) || '' == $comment_author )
            wp_die( __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: please fill the required fields (name, email).') );
        elseif ( !is_email($comment_author_email))
            wp_die( __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: please enter a valid email address.') );
    }

    if ( '' == $comment_content )
        wp_die( __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: please type a comment.') );

    $comment_parent = isset($_POST['comment_parent']) ? absint($_POST['comment_parent']) : 0;

    $commentdata = compact('comment_post_ID', 'comment_author', 'comment_author_email', 'comment_author_url', 'comment_content', 'comment_type', 'comment_parent', 'user_ID');

    $comment_id = wp_new_comment( $commentdata );

    $comment = get_comment($comment_id);
    do_action('set_comment_cookies', $comment, $user);

    $location = empty($_POST['redirect_to']) ? get_comment_link($comment_id) : $_POST['redirect_to'] . '#comment-' . $comment_id;
    $location = apply_filters('comment_post_redirect', $location, $comment);

    wp_safe_redirect( $location );
    exit;
```

А вот функция в файле functions.php, которая обрабатывает комментарий, при нажатии кнопки "Ответить":

```
function mytheme_comment($comment, $args, $depth)
{
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    switch ( $comment->comment_type ) :
        case '' :
?>
       <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
            <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
                <div class="comment-author vcard">
                    <?php edit_comment_link( __( 'Редактировать' ), ' ' ); ?>
                    <?php echo get_avatar( $comment->comment_author_email, $args['avatar_size']); ?>
                    <?php printf(__('<cite class="fn">%s</cite> <span class="says">says:</span>'), get_comment_author_link()) ?>
                </div>

                <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ) ?>"><?php printf(__('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time()) ?></a>
                </div>

<?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
                <div class="comment-awaiting-verification"><?php _e('Ваш ответ ожидает проверки модератором на спам.') ?></div>
             <br />
<?php endif; ?>
                <?php comment_text() ?>
                <div class="reply">
                    <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
                </div>
            </div>

<?php
        break;
        case 'pingback'  :
        case 'trackback' :
?>
            <li class="post pingback">
                <?php comment_author_link(); ?>
                <?php edit_comment_link( __( 'Редактировать' ), ' ' ); ?>
<?php
        break;
    endswitch;
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, что не так. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @eprivalov1, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Дело в том, что я нажимал, но форматирование не сохранилось...

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вызвать комментарии без доп. параметров:

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

Эта функция имеет два аргумента

```
<?php comments_template( $file, $separate_comments ); ?>
```

$file - путь к файлу шаблона (по умолчанию - /comments.php );

$separate_comments - отделение комментария по типу (по умолчанию - false);

А Вы передаете пустую строку аргументу $file.

Пробуйте, если что, заходите на сайт [phpdesigner.in.ua](http://phpdesigner.in.ua/wordpress/) может что-то интерестное для темы найдете.

Закомментируйте функцию комментария в файле function.php и замените содержимое файла comments.php на:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Default_Theme
 */

// Do not delete these lines
    if (!empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) && 'comments.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
        die ('Прямой вызов запрещен!');

    if ( post_password_required() ) { ?>
        <p class="nocomments">Пост защищен паролем. Введите и комментируйте!</p>
    <?php
        return;
    }
?>

<!-- You can start editing here. -->

<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>

    <h3 id="comments"><?php comments_number('Нет комментариев', '1 комментарий', '% коментариев' );?> к записи &#8220;<?php the_title(); ?>&#8221;</h3>

<?php

function mytheme_comment($comment, $args, $depth){
   $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
   <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
     <div class="comment_wrap" id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
        <?php echo get_avatar($comment,$size='64',$default='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/df570c18646109a825ae4acc8d13712d?s=64&d=&r=G' ); ?>
        <?php printf(__('<p class="author">%s</p>'), get_comment_author_link()) ?>
        <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ) ?>"><?php printf(__('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time()) ?></a>
        <?php edit_comment_link(__('(Edit)'),'  ','') ?>
        <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') { ?>
        <em><?php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation.') ?></em>
        <br />
        <?php }else{comment_text();} ?>
        <div class="reply">
            <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
        </div>
     </div>
<?php
}
?>

    <ol class="commentlist">
    <?php wp_list_comments(array('callback'=>'mytheme_comment')); ?>
    </ol>

    <div class="navigation">
        <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_comments_link() ?></div>
        <div class="alignright"><?php next_comments_link() ?></div>
    </div>
 <?php else : // this is displayed if there are no comments so far ?>

    <?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>
        <!-- If comments are open, but there are no comments. -->

     <?php else : // comments are closed ?>
        <!-- If comments are closed. -->
        <p class="nocomments">Комментирование закрыто</p>

    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>
<div id="respond">

<h3><?php comment_form_title( 'Оставь свой отзыв', 'Ответить %s' ); ?></h3>

<div class="cancel-comment-reply">
    <small><?php cancel_comment_reply_link(); ?></small>
</div>

<?php if ( get_option('comment_registration') && !$user_ID ) : ?>
<p>Вы должны быть <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>">авторизированы</a> чтобы оставить комментарий</p>
<?php else : ?>

<form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform">

<?php if ( $user_ID ) : ?>

<p>Вы вошли как <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/profile.php"><?php echo $user_identity; ?></a>. <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="Log out of this account"> Выйти &raquo;</a></p>

<?php else : ?>

<p><input type="text" name="author" id="author" value="<?php echo $comment_author; ?>" size="22" tabindex="1" <?php if ($req) echo "aria-required='true'"; ?> />
<label for="author"><small>Имя <?php if ($req) echo "(обязательно)"; ?></small></label></p>

<p><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $comment_author_email; ?>" size="22" tabindex="2" <?php if ($req) echo "aria-required='true'"; ?> />
<label for="email"><small>Email (не будет опубликовано) <?php if ($req) echo "(обязательно)"; ?></small></label></p>

<p><input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="<?php echo $comment_author_url; ?>" size="22" tabindex="3" />
<label for="url"><small>Сайт</small></label></p>

<?php endif; ?>

<!--<p><small><strong>XHTML:</strong> Вы можете использовать теги: <code><?php echo allowed_tags(); ?></code></small></p>-->

<p><textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="100%" rows="10" tabindex="4"></textarea></p>

<p><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Отправить" />
<?php comment_id_fields(); ?>
</p>
<?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>

</form>

<?php endif; // If registration required and not logged in ?>
</div>

<?php endif; // if you delete this the sky will fall on your head ?>
```

У меня такой подход работает. Потом удалите все Вам не нужное из него.

Comment: Я пробовал, но безрезультатно...

Answer (score 0):

У меня была похожая проблема, оказалось, что когда прописывал аргументы, у 'submit_field' - добавил только одну кнопку сабмита, забыв про дефолтные скрытые инпуты вот и вылетал белый экран.

```
"<input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="68" id="comment_post_ID">
<input type="hidden" name="comment_parent" id="comment_parent" value="0">"
```